# Kendo PanelBar Indent Children / Grand Children

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

Angular

I have a PanelBar with children  / Grand Children. How can I make the children / Grand Children indent an extra 3em so that the children are moved to the right and appear under the parent, offset by a bit.

Right now the children / Grand Children are directly below their parent.

```
    <kendo-panelbar-item title="Orders">
      <kendo-panelbar-item title="Upload Orders"></kendo-panelbar-item>
      <kendo-panelbar-item title="Batch Summary"></kendo-panelbar-item>
    </kendo-panelbar-item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive that with simple css:

```
   .k-panelbar .k-group  {
       padding-left: 10px;
  }
```

Example: [PanelBar indent](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljrggf?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks! - I needed to remove the :: ng-deep but the rest worked well